# Приоритет логических операторов в C++

Tags: c++

Я уже как-то задавал этот вопрос, но нужного мне ответа не получил, поэтому попробую еще раз более подробно.
Если смотреть на таблицу, то можно заметить, что приоритет операторов инкремента и декремента выше, чем приоритет логических операторов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако этот код выведет 100.

```
int x, y, z;
x = y = z = 0;
x++ && y++ && ++z;
cout << x << y << z;
```

Почему сначала не будут выполняться унарные операции, если их приоритет выше?

**Примечание.**
Да, я знаю, как работает логическое AND, и в случае, если первый операнд равен false, то второй рассматриваться не будет. Но вопрос не в этом.

Чтобы лучше понять мой вопрос, рассмотрим, как я представляю выполнение выражения `x++ && y++ && ++z;`. И так смотрим в таблицу, операция с наивысшим приоритетом в нашем случае будет постфиксный ++, значит сразу выполняются x++ и y++, затем по приоритету идет префиксный инкремент, соответсвенно выполняется ++z (операции && пока еще не отработали). И только тогда срабатывает операция &&, но поскольку инкременты уже отработали, то внезависимости от результатов && все три переменных равны 1.